# Parent Field Lookup Via Text (No External id)

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, bulk-api

Just curious how dataloader.io allows the functionality to lookup parent record via text field , email field etc.
https://prnt.sc/wb50K_LtH3mP

Does dataloader.io queries all the parent id via these lookup and then on runtime assign parentid ?
or is there any api functionality which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API in Salesforce that lets you look up parent records this way. You can use External ID fields, but normal text fields can't be used this way. The app would have to query the records, determine if a record should be created (the checkbox option), then choose a record or return an error, based on the settings in this screenshot.